# How to use OpenCL put3DRangeKernel?

Tags: java, opencl, java-3d

I want to process an image in OpenCL, using the Jogamp library in Java.

```
CLCommandQueue queue = device.createCommandQueue();
    queue.putWriteBuffer(input, true);
    kernel.putArg(input)
    .putArg(ouput)
    .putArg(width)
    .putArg(height)
    .putArg(depth);

    int groupSize = Math.min((int) kernel.getWorkGroupSize(device), 16);

    queue.put3DRangeKernel(kernel, 0, 0, 0, width, height, depth, groupSize, groupSize, groupSize);

    queue.flush();
    queue.finish();
    queue.putReadBuffer(output, true);
    output.getBuffer().rewind();
    queue.release();
```

However, I'm not sure how to use put3DRangeKernel and always end up with InvalidWorkGroupSizeExceptions.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jogamp.opencl.CLException$CLInvalidWorkGroupSizeException: can not enqueue 3DRange CLKernel [id: 139725705923824 name: identity]
 with gwo: null gws: {256, 256, 256} lws: {16, 16, 16}
```

The web is lacking samples.

How is put3DRangeKernel used correctly?

**Update**:
device.getMaxImage3dWidth shows 2048 (same with height and depth), so the package size is not the problem.

To give an example, I took an 256 x 256 x 256 image, the localGroupSize is 16. So globalWorkSize % localWorkSize is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [JogAmp documentation for `CLCommandQueue`](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.0.2/javadoc/jocl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opencl/CLCommandQueue.html#put3DRangeKernel%28com.jogamp.opencl.CLKernel,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20long%29), it looks like you are trying to use this function:

```
public CLCommandQueue put3DRangeKernel(CLKernel kernel,
                                       long globalWorkOffsetX,
                                       long globalWorkOffsetY,
                                       long globalWorkOffsetZ,
                                       long globalWorkSizeX,
                                       long globalWorkSizeY,
                                       long globalWorkSizeZ,
                                       long localWorkSizeX,
                                       long localWorkSizeY,
                                       long localWorkSizeZ)
```

Your current call to this function is passing the group size to the global work size parameters, and the image size as the local work size. This is wrong way round - the global work size is the total number of elements you wish to process, and the local work size is the work-group size. You should instead do something like this:

```
queue.put3DRangeKernel(kernel, 0, 0, 0, width, height, depth, groupSize, groupSize, groupSize);
```

This would result in a work-group size of `groupSize*groupSize*groupSize` however, which is likely too large for many devices (maximum work-group sizes are often 1024 or even 256). Try using a smaller work-group size instead, like 16x16x1 for example. You also need to make sure that the local work size exactly divides the global work size.

The function `kernel.getWorkGroupSize(device)` will show you the maximum number of work-items you can have in a work-group for your specific kernel. The work-group size you launch, which is `localWorkSizeX*localWorkSizeY*localWorkSizeZ` needs to be no larger than this. In addition to this constraint on the *total* number of work-items in a work-group, there is also a limit for each individual dimension of the work-group, which you can query with `device.getMaxWorkItemSizes()`.

Comment: Thanks, I swapped global and local sizes but still end up with that exception. Updated the description.

Comment: @Explicat What is the value of `kernel.getWorkGroupSize(device)`? That call will show you the maximum number of work-items you can have in a work-group. If `groupSize*groupSize*groupSize` is bigger than that value (which I strongly suspect it is), then your local work size is invalid.

Comment: You're right! workGroupSize is 512. Needed to change the work group size to 8, as 8 * 8 * 8 = 512. Thank you!